# Selenium IDE : Cannot click on a Vaadin button

Tags: selenium, xpath, vaadin, selenium-ide

I am trying and automate the navigation to an external web site. For that purpose I need to click on a button (to show the following week in a [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) calendar). [Fullcalendar addon for Vaadin looks like this](https://stefan.app.fi/fullcalendar-demo/).

The button is defined in HTML as ([Electron 80](https://www.electronjs.org/) developer tool) :

```
  <div id="content">
    <vaadin-vertical-layout class="layoutCalendar" theme="padding spacing" style="width: 80%;">
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <vaadin-button class="custom-button" theme="icon" tabindex="0" role="button">
                <iron-icon icon="vaadin:angle-double-left"></iron-icon>
            </vaadin-button>
            <vaadin-button class="custom-button" tabindex="0" role="button">Today</vaadin-button>
            <vaadin-button class="custom-button" theme="icon" tabindex="0" role="button">
                <iron-icon icon="vaadin:angle-double-right"></iron-icon>
            </vaadin-button>
            <vaadin-button class="custom-button" theme="icon" tabindex="0" role="button">
                <iron-icon icon="vaadin:calendar"></iron-icon>
                <vaadin-date-picker tabindex="0" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; position: fixed; height: 0px;"></vaadin-date-picker>
            </vaadin-button>
        </div>
        <full-calendar class="calendar" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></full-calendar>
    </vaadin-vertical-layout>
</div>
```

Its xpath (from Firefox 68 dev tools) is defined as :

```
//*[@id="button"]
```

So I added a `click` command in Selenium IDE with the following text in the target field :

```
xpath=//*[@id="button"]
```

But of course as all buttons (namely the previous or today one) share the same id it does not work (`Failed:
09:44:37
Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms`.

So I tried with the xpath of :

```
<vaadin-button class="custom-button" theme="icon" tabindex="0" role="button"><iron-icon icon="vaadin:angle-double-right"></iron-icon></vaadin-button>
```

xpath defined as :

```
/div[1]/vaadin-vertical-layout/div/vaadin-button[3]
```

So in Selenium IDE I entered in the target field :

```
xpath=//div/vaadin-vertical-layout/div/vaadin-button[3]
```

With the same result.

Furthermore using the `Find target in page` does not highlight the button and using `Select target in page` returns `css=calendar-view` and ends in the same way (does not click on the button).

Consequently how can I click on this button and why Selenium IDE doesn't show an error if it can't find the element ? Moreover should I switch Selenium (not the IDE) or is Selenium IDE sufficient for my needs ?

Please note : as it is an external website I don't own, I can't tell which vaadin version is powering the website.

**Edit : trying @Pete's answer below**

I exercized on [Vaadin FullCalendar Addon demo](https://stefan.app.fi/fullcalendar-demo/) and got it working with either `xpath=//vaadin-button[4]` or `xpath=//vaadin-button//span[contains(text(),"Next")]`. I noticed that Selenium IDE was suggesting those xpath while I was entering.

When I did the same on my target website Selenium IDE was only suggesting `xpath=//calendar-view`. Furthermore although the developer tools reported that the next button (which has no text, only the `chevron-right` icon) was actually the 4th `vaadin-button`, Selenium IDE was not able to highlight (aka find)`xpath=//vaadin-button[4]`. This looks weird to me.

What can prevent Selenium IDE to find the button ?

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

From https://stefan.app.fi/fullcalendar-demo/, I wrote these xpaths:

Previous week:

```
XPath = "//vaadin-button//span[contains(text(),"Previous")]"
```

Next week:

```
XPath = "//vaadin-button//span[contains(text(),"Next")]"
```

Today:

```
XPath = "//vaadin-button//span[contains(text(),"Today")]"
```

Comment: Thanks (again) for your answer @Pete. I entered `xpath=//vaadin-button/span[contains(text(),"Next")]` in Selenium IDE and it works for this fullcalendar demo site (it also worked without escaping the second `/`). I also tried `xpath=//vaadin-button[4]` which worked for this demo site. I've updated my my question.